# When do I need use tomcat-coyote.jar - Coyote API?

Tags: api, tomcat

when do I need load the jar tomcat-coyote API in the webserver, for what reason?

I brought this question due to a third-party product that makes use of Coyote API, I guess for some kind of connector but I`m not sure what?

Answer (score 0):

It can be any one of a number of things. That JAR does contain the HTTP and AJP connector implementations but it also has a number of utility classes such as a packaged renamed copy of Apache Commons BCEL used for annotation scanning, some optimized collection implementations, various HTTP utilities (cookies, file upload, header parsing, parameter parsing, etc.) to name but a few.

The quick way to figure out what it is using is to remove the JAR and look for the ClassNotFoundExceptions.